# java.lang.NullPointerException on DiscoveryClient when calling the method from another class

Tags: java, spring, rest, netflix-eureka

When I am calling the method itself through the browser it's working and I am getting the expected `JSON`. So the method is working and the requested service is registered.

```
    @RequestMapping("/getArticle/{articleId}")
public String getArticle(@PathVariable("articleId") Integer articleId) {
    // {"articleId":47,"name":"test","price":5.0}
    List<ServiceInstance> instances = 
discoveryClient.getInstances("articlemicroservice");    //null when calling 
    ServiceInstance serviceInstance = instances.get(0);
    String baseUrl = serviceInstance.getUri().toString();

    baseUrl = baseUrl + "/db/find/" + articleId.toString();

    System.out.println("BASEURL: " + baseUrl);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<String> response = null;

    try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl, HttpMethod.GET, 
getHeaders(), String.class);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    // {"articleId":47,"name":"test","price":5.0}
    String articleEntity = response.getBody().toString();
    System.out.println("articleEntity: " + articleEntity);
    return articleEntity;
}
```

When I am calling the method from another class (which is located in the same project) I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/addCartItemToCart/{cartId}/{articleId}/{quantity}")
public @ResponseBody String addCartItemToCart(@PathVariable("cartId") 
Integer cartId,
        @PathVariable("articleId") Integer articleId, 
@PathVariable("quantity") Integer quantity) {

    ArticleMicroserviceRestConnectorRequester n = new 
ArticleMicroserviceRestConnectorRequester();

    String article = n.getArticle(articleId); //calling the method here
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(article);
    CartItemEntity cartItemEntity = new CartItemEntity();
    cartItemEntity.setArticleId(json.getInt("articleId"));
    cartItemEntity.setQuantity(quantity);
    cartItemEntity.setCartItemId(cartId);
    CartEntity cartEntity = cartRepository.findById(cartId).get();
    cartEntity.addCartItem(cartItemEntity);
    cartEntity.setNumberOfCartItems(cartEntity.getNumberOfCartItems() + 
 cartItemEntity.getQuantity());
    cartRepository.save(cartEntity);
    return "Saved";     
    }
```

Exception:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at de.leuphana.jee.connector.jpa.behaviour.ArticleMicroserviceRestConnectorRequester.getArticle(ArticleMicroserviceRestConnectorRequester.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
...`

Comment: Apparently `discoveryClient` is `null`. How is it initialized/set?

Comment: `@Autowired
 private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;`

Maybe it's not initialized when calling the method from another class but it's initialized when calling the method itself? But if I dont get the reason.

Comment: Wait a second. In `addCartItemToCart` you create a new instance of `ArticleMicroserviceRestConnectorRequester`, right? It is not managed by Spring so `discoveryClient` is not autowired. So of course it is `null`.
You have to inject `ArticleMicroserviceRestConnectorRequester` into your other class so that it is managed by Spring.

Comment: Yep, forgot to use `@Autowired`. I have no idea why I had the idea to initialize it another way. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `addCartItemToCart` you create a new instance of `ArticleMicroserviceRestConnectorRequester`. It is not managed by Spring so `discoveryClient` is not autowired, it is null.

You have to inject `ArticleMicroserviceRestConnectorRequester` into your other class. Thus you will get an instance which is managed by Spring and should have autowired/injected `discoveryClient`.